# How to automate auto-suggestive menu using Selenium through Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to use a while loop to select a city from suggested names of airports. I am only allowed to use send.keys() and while loop. But may code is looping nonstop with out giving an error.

I have tried to play around the while loop:

```
public class syn2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\everybody\\Desktop\\selenium\\library\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://alaskatrips.poweredbygps.com/g/pt/hotels?MDPCID=ALASKA-US.TPS.BRAND.hotels.HOTEL");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin"));
        a.sendKeys("New");
        int i = 0;
        while (a.equals("New Haven, CT (HVN-All Airports)")) {
            driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
            i++;
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
        // System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin")).getAttribute("value"));
        WebElement b = driver.findElement(By.id("FH-destination"));
        b.sendKeys("San Francisco");
        int j = 0;
        while (b.equals("San")) {
            driver.findElement(By.id("FH-destination")).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN);
            j++;
        }
        driver.findElement(By.id("FH-destination")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
    }
```

It should select **New Haven, CT (HVN-All Airports)** and **San Francisco, CA (SFO-San Francisco Intl.)**

Answer (score 0):

This all what you need to select the list item.

```
WebElement a = driver.findElement(By.id("FH-origin"));
a.sendKeys("New");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete-dropdown']/ul/li[contains(.,'New Haven, CT, United States (HVN - All Airports)')]")).click();
```

[image]

Comment: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='autocomplete-dropdown']/ul/li[contains(.,'New Haven, CT, United States (HVN - All Airports)')]")).click();......not working at all. could not find the element by that path

Comment: I am able to select the list item successfully, also added the screenshot which confirms the xpath works. Did you got nosuchelement exception?

Answer (score 0):

To select **New Haven, CT (HVN-All Airports)** as *Leaving from* and **San Francisco, CA (SFO-San Francisco Intl.)** as *Going to* you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
  {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
      ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
      chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
      //chromeOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");
      chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions"); 
      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions); 
      driver.get("https://alaskatrips.poweredbygps.com/g/pt/hotels?MDPCID=ALASKA-US.TPS.BRAND.hotels.HOTEL");
      new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='FrAirport']"))).sendKeys("New");
      new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='FrAirport']//following::div[1]//li/a//ap[text()='(HVN - All Airports)']"))).click();
      new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='DestName']"))).sendKeys("San");
      new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='DestName']//following::div[1]//li/a[contains(., 'Francisco')]"))).click();
  }
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: alaskatrips]

Comment: Thanks alot buddy

Comment: @danfan Glad to be able to help you. Please accept the answer by clicking on the hollow check mark beside my answer which is just below the votedown arrow so the check mark turns green.